# Overlong line even with suggestions for hyphenation

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation

I have a paragraph which starts with

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.6cm}       
\hyphenation{MnTPPCl  CoTPP}
\begin{document}

We studied surface doping with the following molecules:
2,3,5,6-tetrafluoro-7,7,8,8-tetra\-cyano\-quino\-dimethane
(F$_4$TCNQ), manganese(III)-tetra\-phenyl\-porphyrin-chloride
(MnTPPCl), cobalt(II)-tetra\-phenyl\-porphyrin (CoTPP), and
fullerene (C$_{60}$).
\end{document}
```

which ends up to give an overlong line at "(MnTPPCl)"

[image]

Even giving possibilities for hyphenation, it gives me the overlong line with "(MnTPPCl)" sticking out. Why doesn't it just make a line break before "(MnTPPCl)"? How can I prevent it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without a full example, it is impossible to test but presumably breaking the line `(MnTPPCl)` would require stretching the white space more than the specified values.

You can use `\sloppy` to tell LaTeX to allow white space to stretch more than its usual limits.

or as egreg suggested set `\emergencystretch` which is a less aggressive change to teh typesetting quality:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.6cm}       
\hyphenation{MnTPPCl  CoTPP}
\begin{document}
\setlength\emergencystretch{2em}

We studied surface doping with the following molecules:
2,3,5,6-tetrafluoro-7,7,8,8-tetra\-cyano\-quino\-dimethane
(F$_4$TCNQ), manganese(III)-tetra\-phenyl\-porphyrin-chloride
(MnTPPCl), cobalt(II)-tetra\-phenyl\-porphyrin (CoTPP), and
fullerene (C$_{60}$).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I updated it with a minimal example producing the mentioned overlong line.

Comment: Rather than `\sloppy`, something like `\setlength{\emergencystretch}{.3\textwidth}` might give better results, reserving `\sloppy` or (better) the `sloppypar` environment to very tough cases.

Comment: @egreg true but I was thinking chemical names with hyphenation patterns designed for natural language probably is a "tough case" so reached straight for the sledgehammer.

Comment: @user2758804 see update

Comment: @user2758804 -- the line you would like broken has only two spaces in it.  tex can distribute the stretch needed for breaking a line only at the existing spaces, so there is almost no flexibility in this example.  applying `\emergencystratch` as suggested by egreg really requires some attention to the particular circumstance. `sloppypar` is probably the most appropriate action here, as its effect is more "surgical" than global.